# Is it possible to disable _some_ jobs in quartz app?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have an application that uses clustered Quartz jobs, and would like to conditionally disable some (but not all) jobs locally - without overriding the job settings in the DB. So far I have seen solutions that suggest disabling Quartz scheduler altogether, which is not good for my purpose (I want some jobs to run).

In our setting, jobs are typically executed on Dev server, but because developers are often working on code, we do want to be able to execute code locally, while common shared DB is accessed.

The problem seem to be that Quartz is taking job configuration stored in DB as gospel, and there seem to be nothing I can do locally to say "No, please don't run this job!" If I don't instantiate job trigger, Quartz would still instantiate QuartzJobBean, and attempt to run it.

There are two solutions that I see, but don't like:

1. Reset the schedule to "0 0 0 0 0 ?". That would disable the job, but not only locally - it would override job setting in DB, until another (active) instance would run in the same cluster, and schedule would be reset again... messy.
2. Pretend to be executed. When "executeInternal()" is called, skip execution. This would make the Quartz think that the job was executed, when in fact it was not. Again, good for me, but not good for the cluster.

Does Quartz has the ability for application to say "Ignore me! This app instance is not active to execute this particular job", or it is essentially "all or nothing" when comes to individual jobs?

Comment: Is the DB also local?. Or is it just the App that's running locally?

Comment: @TheLostMind App is local, but DB is shared (I realize that's part of the problem, but we do need to use shared DB).

Comment: In that case don't update the DB - it's dangerous. I would recommend having a property in your app that can be overridden when running the app locally. Then based on this property's value (LOCAL or PROD), create a strategy pattern for each quartz job and choose the appropriate strategy. The LOCAL job should just be a NO-OP job.

Comment: @TheLostMind some jobs we do want to be executed locally. For other, non-local jobs, no-op execution is my "option #2", and problem there is that Quartz would think that job has executed successfully (and won't try to engage another node to do it) while actually it's not.

Comment: Well, you are asking for something that's hard to do.. Because you are breaking how quartz should be used. Why would you want to execute a job on one machine and not execute it on another?. And since all the machines (apps) are connecting to the same DB, you've no control over which device will be picked to run the quartz job. I honestly see no way of fixing your problem.. Can I ask you why do you want it this way?

Comment: @TheLostMind that's primarily for debugging purposes, and secondary for load balancing.

Comment: 1. Debugging code can always be shipped to prod. So, using locally is not necessary.

2. Quartz intrinsically doesn't provide fairness in any way. So, load balancing using / for quartz triggers is an incorrect  use of the framework :)

Comment: @TheLostMind "Debugging code can always be shipped to prod" - you mean, do debugging on server? Yes, but this is not just the debugging, it's a full tweak-build-deploy development process. Too hard to do for more than one developer at a time.